# is there a difference between implicit cast vs 'as' keyword in dart?

Tags: dart

Is there any difference between using an implicit cast to cast in dart vs the 'as' keyword? Will they result in the same (or similar) runtime error if the type is not as expected?

For example:

```
dynamic foo = "blah";
String boo = foo; // is this
String boo2 = foo as String; // the same as this?
```

Answer (score 1):

No. And yes.
TL;DR: Don't worry about the difference, just do what reads the best.

If your program is correct, and the casts will succeed, then there is unlikely to be any difference.

When inferring types, `String boo = foo;` will infer the type of `foo` with a context type of `String`. If the resulting static type of `foo` then turns out to be `dynamic` then it implies an implicit downcast from `dynamic` to `String.

For `String boo = foo as String;`, the static type of `foo` is inferred with no context type. No matter what the resulting static type is, it will be cast to `String` at run-time.

You can see a difference between these two if you have a more complicated expression than just the variable `foo`:

```dart
T first<T extends dynamic>(List<T> list) => list.first;
String boo = first([1]); // <- compile-time error
String boo2 = first([1]) as String;
```

With this example, you get a *compile-time* error in the `boo` line because the compiler knows that the list should be a `List<String>`. There is no error in the `boo2` line because the list only needs to be a `List<dynamic>`, and whatever `first` returns is then dynamically cast to `String`.

A more contrived example would be:

```dart
T firstOrDefault<T extends dynamic>(List<T> list) {
  if (list.isEmpty) {
    // Invent some default values for known types.
    if (null is T) return null as T;
    if (0 is T) return 0 as T;
    if (0.0 is T) return 0.0 as T;
    if ("" is T) return "" as T;
    if (false is T) return false as T;
    throw UnsupportedError("No default value for the needed type");
  }
  return list.first;
}
String boo = firstOrDefault([]); // <- returns "", with null safety.
String boo2 = firstOrDefault([]) as String; // <- returns null, throws.
```

(Doing that kind of type-parameter specialization is not a recommended programming style. It's too fragile *precisely because* it can be affected in unpredictable ways by subtle changes to static types.).

Ignoring inference and static checking, there is *not much* difference at run-time. If `foo` is just a simple expression with static type `dynamic`, then the language requires downcast to `String` in both situations.

*However*, the Dart2JS web compiler can enable *unsound optimizations* which basically omit implicit downcasts entirely (as an "optimization" assume that they would have succeeded) and the go on with potentially type-unsound values flowing around.
For that reason, some people (mainly those coding for the web) may prefer to use implicit downcasts over explicit downcasts.

Dart with null safety only has implicit downcasts from `dynamic`.
You can always force an implicit downcast from *any* type by doing:

```dart
String boo3 = foo as dynamic;
```

The `as dynamic` is a free up-cast, it has no effect at run-time (it can't fail and the compiler knows that), so all it does is change the static type of the expression ... to something which introduces an implicit downcast, which the dart2js compiler will then (unsoundly) ignore as well.
(Use with caution, as with everything involving `dynamic`. Also, the analyzer might warn about an "unnecessary up-cast".)